# Firebase negativ topic condition stop working

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Actually today I received a customer report.

The push notification do not arrive at the devices.

After some research I figured out that the negative topic condition I use to send notifications to all devices, stop working.
One week ago the sending worked well with the same condotions.
I uses Postman for developing the requests.

I use the Rest API with "send" endpoint.
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

here is my payload:

```
{
    "condition":"!('nonExistingTopic' in topics)",
    "data": {
        "notification_foreground": true,
        "link": "https://www.google.com"
    },
    "notification": {
        "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
        "title": "notification title",
        "body": "notification message"
    }
}
```

I received an "ok"-status from Firebase ad the "message_id", but no message was send. So obviously the condition do not fit to any of the devices.

When I use the field "registration_ids" with a fcm token of my device I receive the notification.

I allready tried to find some kind of Update changes in firebase changelogs, that maybe changed the behavior of the condition field. But I did not find anything.

Does anybody have the same problems?
Any ideas for a work around!

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile i found a solution for this problem.

I only use the condition-field for really existing topics.

```
"condition" = "'sport' in topics"
```

To send a message to all devices you can use the "to" parameter with the value "/topics/all", instead of the "negativ" condition.

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "myTitle",
        "body": "myTeaser"
    },
    "to": "/topics/all",
    "data": {
        "myCustomDataField": "myFieldValue"         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here, as temporary solution I have to send notifications thought Firebase Console (because I use it just for communication with users).

Also I will launch a new update that now it is registering to a topic called "general" when start up.

I didn't figure out how to send to all users using negative topic condition. It stopped working about 10 days ago.